# SQL Connection with public IP, named instance and port number

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have had difficulty creating a connection string in c# that will connect to a remote SQL server using a public IP, named instance and a port number (other than 1433). Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is an excellent site for connection string questions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this, replacing 666 with the port number you want to use, 190.190.200.100 with the IP address you want, etc.:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100\MyInstance,666;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Is it necesary `Network Library=DBMSSOCN;`? @RedFilter

Answer (score 7):

Using the servername `tcp:<public IP>,<port>`, as documented in [SqlConnection.ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx):

> The name or network address of the
>   instance of SQL Server to which to
>   connect. The port number can be
>   specified after the server name:
>
> `server=tcp:servername, portnumber`
>
> When specifying a local instance,
>   always use (local). To force a
>   protocol, add one of the following
>   prefixes:
>
> `np:(local)`, `tcp:(local)`, `lpc:(local)`
>
> Data Source must use the TCP format or
>   the Named Pipes format.
>
> TCP format is as follows:
>
> - `tcp:<host name>\<instance name>`
> - `tcp:<host name>,<TCP/IP port number>`

If you use the `tcp:<host name>\<isntance name>` the SQL Browser service connection is required (port 1433) therefore is better to use the later format, with explicit port name:

```
Data Source=tcp:1.2.3.4,1234;User Id=...; Password=...
```

Answer (score 1):

[This site has never failed me.](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

And i am gonna state the obvious here, but it is generally a bad idea to expose your sql server on the internet.. (unless you are using VPN)

Answer (score 0):

```
connectionString="Database=pub;Server=192.168.1.1\INSTANCE,1746;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

Or you could use `username/password` instead of trusted connection.

Comment: Not sure about a local IP but if you try this it will not work with a public IP.

Comment: Yes, you would have to change the IP address, if you can resolve ip address it should work, I have done it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below, add the port number after the IP or domain name with comma.

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=www.yourdomain.com,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;Password=yourstringpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```