# Configuration system failed to initialize when trying to connect using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, app-config, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect from my app to SQL server and im getting the following error: "Configuration system failed to initialize".

this is my App.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <ConnectionString>
    <add name="ConStr" ConnectionString="Data Source=10.0.0.111;Initial Catalog=InfoDesk;User ID=sa" />
  </ConnectionString>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

and this is from the app:

```
SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString);
```

Endless glory for a good answer

Thanks,
Erez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) Page. There is an example for a connection-string for the sql-server 2005.

I'm not sure, but I think you have to specify the databaseprovider in your connectionstring.

Update:

Found something at connectionstrings.com for SQL-Server 2008:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461005/sql-connection-with-public-ip-named-instance-and-port-number). Maybe you have a problem with the IP

Comment: Just saw that the inner exception is:
Unrecognized configuration section ConnectionString. in line 3

Comment: Do you provide a valid password in your connection-string?

Comment: no... and im copying the connection string from the properties of the database in the Server Explorer in VS2012

Comment: The weirdest thing just happened:
I decided to test the connection with a fresh solution and it worked like a charm, don't know why but i copy-paste it exactly the same...

Lest call it a "Feature" :)
thanks anyway for the mental support