# Connect to SQL Server remotely from outside VPN using WPF application

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string, remote-server

I have a WPF database application on client machine. The SQL Server is in my home office (so the server is outside of the client's network.) I used the following connection string on my network while building the application:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source= PrivateIPAddressofServer\ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS,1434; Initial Catalog=NameofDatabase; User ID = userid; Password = password;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am able to connection to the server from production machine without any issues (production machine is in my home.) However, when testing the app using  "PublicIPAddress\ComputerName\SQLEXPRESS, 1434" I get the following error

```
Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
```

I am 100% sure that I have the correct credentials to log into the SQL Server, that the server is configured to allow remote connection, and that port 1433 and 1434 are open as I followed this article to troubleshoot the error [How to Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx). In addition, I called my internet provider for them to configure my home network to allow for remote connection from outside.

However, I am still experiencing the same error message! Does anyone have other ideas for me to try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.
[SQL Connection with public IP, named instance and port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461005/sql-connection-with-public-ip-named-instance-and-port-number)

Why do you have \ComputerName in the connection string?