# Can't connect to an online SQL Server (ERROR:25 , ERROR:87)

Tags: sql-server

I'd wish to set my local SQL as a server online that my other project partners will be able to connect to (I'm currently using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio).

I added all of the needed ports to the firewall, and enabled SQL Browser. My ip address is static and I know all the needed details about my instance name. I worked by a tutorial I saw online so everything should be working.
But unfortunately, I'm getting an error while trying to connect from another computer.

[image]

This is the error I'm getting. Anyone?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You either have the server name incorrect, the server isn't allowed to accept remote connections or the connection string is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm you have remote connections enabled. From your local machine:

1. Open SQL SERVER Management Studio
2. Connect to your server
3. In Object Explorer, right-click on the server and choose Properties
4. From "Select a Page" choose, "Connections"
5. Confirm "Allow Remote Connections to this server" is enabled.

You can also do this:

`EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access', N'1'`

`GO`

`RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE`

`GO`

Comment: The "Allow Remote Connections to this server" was already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:

[SQL Connection with public IP, named instance and port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461005/sql-connection-with-public-ip-named-instance-and-port-number)

The default port for SQL Server is 1433