# application connection to SQL Server remotely wouthout RDC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I need to allow a 3rd party web application to connect to my SQL Server database. ( 2014 Express )
The web application does not reside in the same network. 
The SQL Server can be connected to the internet.
Have a few questions.

1 - Can I allow the we application to connect via ODBC ( as they requested this )?     or is there any other way such as connection string ?
I would like to know know how to do this, such as connection string, router configurations required etc... please.

Comment: Setup a VPN between the two sites, then the remote can access it via an internal IP address.

Comment: Hi Alex,  is there a way without VPN that you can suggest ?

Comment: It's a really bad idea (security wise) to open up your SQL Server for direct access across the internet (via ODBC, ADO, or any other protocol). Either you should host their web application, or use a VPN so that you know which traffic is trustworthy, or write your own API layer that you host and they consume from their web application.

Comment: You mean such as create a web service and expose data that way ?

Comment: Yes, that is the third option I suggested. You can then control authentication, as well as limit what databases they can access on that server, and limit the actions you permit on that data at a much finer grain than what you will get through SQL permissions. You SQL Server then sits in the private zone with no internet access, which is a +1 for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a VPN to connect, but I suggest you to write a web service to interact with the web application. That is the ideal way to expose database to 3rd party application..

Comment: I am trying to connect via public ip address instead of vpn for the moment. As a side question is  vpn an efficient way for web applications to connect to a remote SQL server ?

Comment: How would you create a connections string for a sql database with following :  has public ip address with port , sql server is 2014 express and is a named instance with a port . I have tried many different ways and failed so far.

Comment: @idkd - for the connection strings, please follow the below links. Have you tried connecting to the SQL Server remotely via Sql Server Management studio? 
.
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461005/sql-connection-with-public-ip-named-instance-and-port-number

Comment: @idkd - yes VPN is a secured & efficient way according to my knowledge.